# How to drag window using right click down with AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to drag window using right click with title bar just like left click. Is it possible do that with AutoHotkey?

Background : *I use Dell Display Manager which lets me arrange my windows in pre-defined grid. I can do this directly dragging or Shift+ Drag. Both options are sub optimal. Direct dragging just forces unwanted resize. Shift and Drag requires a key and mouse. I am wondering if I can drag using right click. I use application called RBTray to minimize to tray using right click. So, I know we can definitely add something like. I am looking something in AutoHotkey as that's much easier to code than C++.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/index.htm#EasyWindowDrag

Below is code adapted to right click:

```
~RButton::
CoordMode, Mouse  ; Switch to screen/absolute coordinates.
MouseGetPos, EWD_MouseStartX, EWD_MouseStartY, EWD_MouseWin
WinGetPos, EWD_OriginalPosX, EWD_OriginalPosY,,, ahk_id %EWD_MouseWin%
WinGet, EWD_WinState, MinMax, ahk_id %EWD_MouseWin% 
if EWD_WinState = 0  ; Only if the window isn't maximized 
    SetTimer, EWD_WatchMouse, 0 ; Track the mouse as the user drags it.
return

EWD_WatchMouse:
GetKeyState, EWD_LButtonState, RButton, P
if EWD_LButtonState = U  ; Button has been released, so drag is complete.
{
    SetTimer, EWD_WatchMouse, Off
    return
}
GetKeyState, EWD_EscapeState, Escape, P
if EWD_EscapeState = D  ; Escape has been pressed, so drag is cancelled.
{
    SetTimer, EWD_WatchMouse, Off
    WinMove, ahk_id %EWD_MouseWin%,, %EWD_OriginalPosX%, %EWD_OriginalPosY%
    return
}
; Otherwise, reposition the window to match the change in mouse coordinates
; caused by the user having dragged the mouse:
CoordMode, Mouse
MouseGetPos, EWD_MouseX, EWD_MouseY
WinGetPos, EWD_WinX, EWD_WinY,,, ahk_id %EWD_MouseWin%
SetWinDelay, -1   ; Makes the below move faster/smoother.
WinMove, ahk_id %EWD_MouseWin%,, EWD_WinX + EWD_MouseX - EWD_MouseStartX, EWD_WinY + EWD_MouseY - EWD_MouseStartY
EWD_MouseStartX := EWD_MouseX  ; Update for the next timer-call to this subroutine.
EWD_MouseStartY := EWD_MouseY
return
```